# PHP change timestamp only in PHP date

Tags: php

I have a date and i would like to only modify the time stamp in it and keep the day month year the same. Any way to do this?

The date i have this 
2017-07-12 13:41:23

I have tried creating the date as

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , strtotime(strtr("12-07-2017 13:41:23", "/", "-")))
```

Thanks

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Need a way to change only the timestamp on the date string

Comment: What you want to change exactly? change time (i.e: 13:41:23) or format of time?

Comment: No change the time to current time

Comment: Changing only the time component of a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object is the only purpose in life for its [`setTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) method.

Comment: Nobody understands what you want to achieve, at the moment you have no timestamp printed. You only have the date.

Comment: do you see the time after the date in my example above?

Comment: Your question is confusing people. I think you are confusing "time" with "timestamp". A timestamp in programming contexts refers to the [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

(date("Y-m-d" , strtotime("12-07-2017 13:41:23")). " ".date("H:i:s"));

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you need

```
$xx = '12-07-2017 13:41:23';
$result = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($xx)) . date('H:i:s', time());
```

Answer (score 0):

When modifying dates and times, save yourself a world of pain and use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. To set the time on a timestamp to the current time, simply use [DateTime::setTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime("12-07-2017 13:41:23");
$date->setTime(date('G'),date('i'),date('s'));
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Outputs 2017-07-12 01:36:29
```